# why max-width in media query is not working

Tags: css, max, media

I wrote this piece of code but it's not working

```
@media  (max-width: 767px){  

.navbar-brand {     
     padding-top: 10px;     
     height: 80px;  
}  
.navbar-brand h1{   
     padding-top: 10px;     
     font-size: 5vw;  
}  
.navbar-brand p {   
     font-size: .6em;   
     margin-top: 12px;  
}  
.navbar-brand p img {       
     height: 20px ;  
}  

#collapsable-nav a {    
     font-size: 1.2em; 
}  

#collapsable-nav a span{    
     font-size: 1em;  
} 
}
```

I want to change my `navbar` when the screen is smaller than **767px** but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? See also: [ask].

Answer (score 1):

use min-width instead of using max-width

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-brand {
        padding-top: 10px;
        height: 80px;
      }
      .navbar-brand h1{
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 5vw;
      }
      .navbar-brand p {
        font-size: .6em;
        margin-top: 12px;
      }
      .navbar-brand p img {
        height: 20px;
      }
      #collapsable-nav a {
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
      #collapsable-nav a span{
        font-size: 1em;
      }
    }
```

Visit the following link to understand more about min-widht in css:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_min-width

Answer (score -2):

You should probably use min-width for your media query in this case.

Comment: This answer lacks an explanation and or code that applies to the question. Note that the [answer by Syaifal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987714/why-max-width-in-media-query-is-not-working/74988385#74988385) also suggested using `min-width` but provided accompanying code, thus making this answer redundant...